# Tree identification

Tags: identification, trees

Can anyone say with certainty what this species of tree this is, found in Northern Michigan? The pic was taken today.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I'd say it's a kind of willow (salix), but more details will give you a more precise id. For example where does it grow (type of soil, wet or dry...) and perhaps a photo of the whole tree so that we can see the shape and size.

Comment: Right, a photo of all tree, bark, single leave (with attachment to branch) are needed. In general: bark and detail of leaves are not necessary if the photo is high resolution (so that we can zoom).

Comment: Thank you both. I have concluded that it is a Salix, perhaps S. bebbiana. Much appreciated!

Comment: @user19938 If you want, you can answer you're own question and add pics to include what the entire tree looks like. Other users may have the same tree or are curious (like I am!!) And then your post will also shows as "answered"... Just a suggestion :) Welcome to Gardening Stack Exchange!!!

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Midge that the proposed willow and toothed leaves do not match, I don't think it is a beech. By now of course the OP will have seen flowers and fruit and there will be no further doubt what it is. Stephie's request about dry or wet soil is important. My own inclination is to say it is a Whitebeam (*Sorbus aria*) variety.